# CI Login with session

Tags: codeigniter

I want to login to the admin page using session but it seems like the session is not working i already include the session in autoload.php im using codeigniter.

here is the code

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Username','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','required');

    if($this->form_validation->run()){
        //variables
        $username = $this->input->post('username');
        $password = md5($this->input->post('password'));
        //model function
        $this->load->model('main_model');
        if($this->main_model->can_login($username,$password)){
            $session_data = array(
                `username` => $username
            );
            $this->session->set_userdata($session_data);
            redirect(base_url() . 'home/admin');
        }
        else{
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Invalid Username and Password');
            redirect(base_url() . 'home/index');
        }
    }
    else{
        $this->index();
    }
```

Comment: Please verify that `session` is loaded in `config.php`

Comment: I'm sure you are trying to understand how the whole system works but in future I would suggest you go for Community Auth library or IonAuth. It will save you a lot of headache

Answer (score 0):

You are not giving the name to session values to save and retrieve.

Do like this.

```
$session_data = array(
  'username' => $username
);
$this->session->set_userdata('values', $session_data);
```

Get session values

```
$this->session->userdata['values']['username']
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Change ` to '
2. Add `'logged_in' => TRUE` if it's Loggin session
3. Remove remove `values` in `set_userdata`

**Code**

```
$session_data = array(
    'username' => $username, #Change
    'logged_in' => TRUE #add
 );

$this->session->set_userdata($session_data); #Change
```

To access data

```
$this->session->userdata('username');
```

---

**FYI**

> `$this->session->set_userdata('key', $value);` is used for add singal session